# MS Access 2010, Validaton Rule: Query-based Fields 1, 2 and 3 cannot be equal to each other

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, validationrules

I have a table that has FiscalLider, FiscalDia and FiscalNoite fields, their values comes from a Query and if I choose a name for one field that name should not be used on the other two fields, like this:

- Value FiscalLider can´t be used on Value FiscalDia or Value FiscalNoite
- Value FiscalNoite can´t be used on Value FiscalDia or Value FiscalLider
- Value FiscalDia can´t be used on Value FiscalDia or Value FiscalLider

For example:

The Query fetch me these results as dropdown list on the field:

1. John
2. Paul
3. Michael
4. Margareth
5. Philip

On FiscalLider field I choose Paul, so that name will become unavailable for FiscalDia or Value FiscalNoite, remaining only

1. John
2. Michael
3. Margareth
4. Philip

Then I have chosen John as FiscalDia, then on FiscalNoiite field the possible options would be

1. Michael
2. Margareth
3. Philip

If user decides to go change any Fiel´s value, then he could chose between only the name on that Field plus Michael, Margareth and Philip since these are the only names not assigned to any field.

I have tried to put the validation rule [FiscalDia]<>[FiscalNoite]<>[FiscalLider] on the validation rule inside every field but I get a SQL error: 
"Invalid SQL syntax - cannot use multiple columns in a column-level CHECK constraint".

Based on this error I am not sure if I should put the constraint on the SQL of the Query or not. But anyway I do not know how to do that.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help communicate what you want to do.

Comment: Sure thing. I will post a file in a a couple of hours.

Comment: . . I don't think this is an MS Access issue.  I think it is an application issue.